# How to reference preceding/subsequent values in a pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, series

I want to use both the current `value` AND preceding `value` in a pandas series object.
Currently I'm trying to do this in a for-loop iterating with `.iteritems()` and  a nested `if`-statement, as follows:

```
for index, value in gdp['Recession_start'].iteritems():

    if value & "value+1":

        Recession_start=gdp['Quarter'].iloc[index]
        print(Recession_start)
```

My DataFrame(**gdp**) is this:

```
 Quarter   Recession_start

 2000q1    False

 2000q2     False

 2000q3     True

 2000q4     True

 2001q1     False
```

I want to know how I could refer the different value. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Option 1***
**`shift`** with **`loc`**

```
df.loc[df.Recession_start & df.Recession_start.shift(-1), 'Quarter']
```

***Option 2***
**`astype(int)`** with **`diff`**

```
df.loc[~df.Recession_start.astype(int).diff().ne(1), 'Quarter']
```

Both result in:

```
2    2000q3
Name: Quarter, dtype: object
```

---

<sub>`Python 3.6.4, Pandas 0.22.0`</sub>